# Issue with CSS selector

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I'm having an issue with CSS. It seems to only select items with the `:last-child` pseudo selector.

My markup:

```
<tr class="emtpy-row">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

My CSS:

```
.THIS .empty-row td,
.THIS .emtpy-row td:last-child {
    background-color: hotpink;
}
```

But, only the second `td` turns pink.

This is very strange to me. Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Could it be possible that an another style is applied with a higher priority rule? By precising :last-child, your rule is prioritized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a typo. Your CSS says `.THIS .empty-row td,`, but the class is `emtpy-row`.

The `:last-child` pseudo-selector does not have the typo.